# Editor wysiwyg, como puxar o conteúdo do textarea e inserir no banco mysql com php

Tags: php, javascript, html, wysiwyg

tentei conseguir puxar as informações contidas no textarea, ou seja o editor wysiwyg, com o texto devidamente formatado e em seguida incluir no banco de dados mysql, o que ocorre no momento é que o mesmo só puxa as informações contidas no input.

os arquivos de origem do editor estão também em:

https://github.com/suyati/line-control

Desde já agradeço a ajuda e disposição !

Segue abaixo o HTML index.php correspondente:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="editor.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
               //esse é o script padrão para exibição do editor
                $("#txtEditor").Editor();

                //essa deveria ser a solução para uso via GET mais quando a utilizo o editor some..
                $("#txtEditor").Editor('getText');

            });
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link href="editor.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <title>LineControl | v1.1.0</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <form method="POST" action="?paginas=teste" name="form_redacao" id="form_redacao" onsubmit="return enviardados();" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
                        <label>Título</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" id="titulo_from" name="titulo_from">

                        <label>Conteúdo</label>
                        <textarea id="txtEditor" name="txtEditor"></textarea>
                        <br>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="btn-enviar" value="Mostrar Resultado">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

E aqui o cadastramento do conteúdo teste.php, como menciono antes, só vem o conteúdo de Titulo, e consigo inseri-lo no mysql.

```
<?php

//if (isset($_POST['btn-enviar'])) {
    try{
        /*Pega as informações vindas do formulario*/

        $titulo_from = $_POST['titulo_from'];

        $redacao_from = $_POST['txtEditor'];

        /*executa a inclusão no banco de dados*/
        $inserir = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO conteudo (titulo_redacao, text_redacao) VALUES (:titulo_redacao, :text_redacao)");

        /*associa aos campos com o do formulario*/

        $inserir->bindValue(':titulo_redacao', $titulo_from);
        $inserir->bindValue(':text_redacao', $redacao_from);


        $inserir->execute();


        echo $titulo_from;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $redacao_from;

        var_dump($inserir);

        if ($inserir == true){
                echo "
                    <script language='javascript'>
                        window.alert('Mensagem enviada com sucesso.');
                        /*window.location = 'index.php?paginas=pagseguro_listar';*/
                    </script>
                    "; 
        }else{ 
                echo "
                    <script language='javascript'>
                        window.alert('Falha ao enviar sua menssagem.');
                        /*window.location = 'index.php?paginas=form_pag_cadastro';*/
                    </script>
                    "; 
        }



    }catch(PDOExcception $erro){
        echo $erro->getmessage();
    }
//}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tem alguns problemas no seu codigo, mas pra detectar o seu erro mesmo precisamos ver até onde o texto que você digita chega, você ja tentou darum var_dump na $_POST antes de

```
        $inserir = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO conteudo (titulo_redacao, text_redacao) VALUES (:titulo_redacao, :text_redacao)");
```

Repare que acessando a glbal $_Post diretamente você fica sujeito a alguns tipos de ataque, mesmo usando o bindvalue

Comment: então, de fato não havia tentar dar um var_dump() antes do $inserir, porem acabo de fazer essa tentativa.. var_dump($titulo_from,$redacao_from);  o que ocorre é que o segundo valor o $redacao_form ele já vem de cara vazio... ou seja tudo que eu digito no editor é ignorado..

Comment: o pior é que o JS do editor não está acusando qualquer tipo de erro.. me deixando no escuro...

Comment: cara se o valor nao ta vindo, provavelmente você ta colocando algum nome no textarea e buscando outro nome pra jogar na variavel

Comment: pensei nisso um tempo depois mais, refiz o teste tomando esse cuidado. o que o corre é que só consigo obter o valor vindo do input, o que vem do editor me vem sempre com o length 0, ou seja nulo.

Comment: me passa o seu formulario ai, so o formulario

Comment: <form method="POST" action="?paginas=teste" name="form_redacao" id="form_redacao" onsubmit="return enviardados();" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" id="titulo_from" name="titulo_from">
    <textarea id="txtEditor" name="txtEditor"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="btn-enviar" value="Mostrar Resultado">
</form>

Comment: acredito que o seu problema é esse //if (isset($_POST['btn-enviar'])) {, o codigo de verificação do botao esta comentado tira o comentario e faz o codigo rodar apenas se o click no botão existir

Comment: na verdedade coloquei o comentario nessa linha porque ele nem se quer exibia o var_dump(); com ela ativa.. e mesmo com ela ativa... O funcionamento é o mesmo... ou seja só puxa os dados vindos do input. os que veem do editor wysiwyg, não veem nada length=0 entendeu..? a linha de comando $("#txtEditor").Editor('getText'); segundo a documentação do mesmo deveria solucionar isso, mais por alguma razão não está captando o conteúdo..